Zero-cost integer upcast via inline assembly
Is it possible to manufacture, as a macro, a sort of zero-cost integer upcast via inline assembly?
In many instances, I would like to pass 32 bit integers, which are already "in place" through interfaces that take 64 bit integers. But C doesn't like leaving upper bits indeterminate and casting or trying to extend the 32 bits to 64 via a union makes compilers either zero-extend or sign-extend the 32 bit number.
Dummy example:
void g(unsigned long );
void f(int X){
    unsigned long XX = (unsigned)X; //mov %edi, %edi
    g(XX);
}

Is it possible to replace the cast with some JUST_PRETEND_ITS_AN_UNSIGNED_LONG_WITHOUT_DOING_ANYTHING(X)?

Which do you want? zero extend or sign extend? Where  long's size is greater, you have to decide.

@SimonGoater Neither. Leave the upper bits as they were.

There are portability issues but you can do it with a union with elements int x[2] and unsigned long.

@SimonGoater As I say in the question, unions I've already tried: https://godbolt.org/z/WTrdx34Tf => zero-extension.

You have to make the int array in the union for my suggestion. Did you try that?

So the function takes an unsigned long, but it ignores the upper 32 bits so you can leave them indeterminate?

@Barmar Correct. I'm using longs (uintptr_t) just as context storage for some callbacks. Some callbacks use the full 64 bits. Others will cast it down to 32 bit, so for those, it's perfectly fine for the upper bits to be garbage.

Make f (as shown) with __attribute__((always_inline))? AFAICT, that's as fast as it gets. With inline the caller of f may generate 32 bit values directly throughout. In any case, aren't we talking about a single asm inst?

What makes you think there is any cost savings to be had here?  Or if there were, that it would be enough to justify any effort in this direction?

Note well that all arguments are passed by value, so there is going to be a copy performed in any case.  On most platforms, that will be into a register, and in a case such as is presented, I expect a decent compiler to already use an efficient (probably the most efficient) mechanism for loading a 64-bit register with a 32-bit value, with or without sign-extension as the combination of C data types requires.  I don't see any reason to expect that you could add code (even assembly) to make it any more efficient.

@JohnBollinger Great question. I posted a super dummy example. In fact I have lots of this and these, each taking six uintptr_t context arguments and it's arranged by this to save codesize and the compiler was messing that up a bit w/ those zero extends, which add up. I may not end up using what I found, but it was fun exploring this. :D Posted my finding thanks to whoever upvoted the question. I was ready to delete it because of the downvote. :)

@JohnBollinger With the code I'm working with, things are already arranged for the arguments to be in place (I'm taking function pointers as last arguments), so if there's no sign/zero-extending mov, there will be no movs => codesavings <=> what I was after.

With inline, the caller of f has to calculate the value for X. Say that value is in eax/rax. It has to put it in edi/rdi. It does this with a mov* inst. It will figure out whether the mov is simple, sign extending, or zero extending. This is zero overhead. Caller [probably] has to generate this mov in any case

@PetrSkocik, I'm having trouble visualizing the situation you describe.  If the example presented in the question is not representative of your actual case, then that probably means you have asked the wrong question.  I still don't think you are likely to do better without abandoning C altogether (and perhaps not even then), but I feel pretty confident that you're not going to get the answer you're looking with the question as presently formulated.

Just declare f to take an unsigned long. Then the compiler doesn't have to "pretend" that it's an unsigned long. it is an unsigned long.

For an alternative to your union code, what about asm volatile ("jmp g\n"); since that's what you're trying to generate. It might have an extra (not executed) ret at the end, but who cares?

@CraigEstey There's many ways to achieve that codegen. I was looking just for what the question was asking because of how it fits with other things.  The answer I posted answers it sufficiently.

Again, we're talking about eliding a single mov inst. Whatever g does, it's now under tremendous pressure to not blow the savings by introducing a single extra inst ;-)

I would [again] ask whether f can be inline?

@CraigEstey dummy examples != real code. And no, inlining's not applicable/useful in my use case.

Then, you don't have an MRE for your real code here. We'd need examples of all relevant g functions with corresponding f variants. To my mind, you want different f versions that force the desired behavior: unchanged, sign extend, zero extend, etc. Then, we could suggest ways to optimize/improve them further, which is what you wanted, l believe.

@JohnBollinger the language specifies that in the original code, the upper 32 bits of the parameter must be given values. The compiler can't optimize that away.  (Well , it could in theory analyze the called function to see if the bits are used, but compilers aren't actually going to do that).

Of course, @M.M.  When I said "with or without sign-extension as the combination of C data types requires", I meant sign-extension as opposed to zero-extension, not as opposed to "keep random bits".  As is usually the case in C, the semantics are defined in terms of values, not their representations.

You can use the "<digit>" option of gcc inline asm to say that the input and output need to be the same register, and then do nothing: void f(int X) { unsigned long XX; __asm__("" : "=r"(XX) : "0" (X)); g(XX); } This auto-adapts to the case where the parameter is passed on the stack or if an alignment or packing constraint prevents the two from aliasing.

@RaymondChen Thanks. Yes. The <digit> constraint is what I was looking for. (I figured that out yesterday and posted it as an answer in case others want it)

A combo of unions and inline assembly matching constraints seems to have done it:
#include <stdint.h>
void takeUptr(uintptr_t U);
#define upcast(X)  ({ union { int x; uintptr_t xx; } u; u.x = X; \
    asm("":"=r"(u.xx):"0"(u.x)); /*make C think the upper bits are inited*/ \
    u.xx; })

void passAsUptr(int x){ takeUptr(upcast(x)); } 
//^jmp takeUptr; //no zero/sign-extending mov ✓
uintptr_t retAsUptr(int x){ return upcast(x); } 
//^movl %edi, %eax; ret; //correctly moved to the output register ✓

https://godbolt.org/z/vz9W5Mq8M
On gcc (sadly not clang) this eliminates the zero-extending mov when moving from
a 32-bit to a 64-bit number when they're both mapped to the same register. The key was using the positional 0 constraint to make the register of the input (here u.x) match the register of the output (u.xx, at position 0, hence constraint 0).

Code is wrong. The problem is you are not actually guaranteed the upper bits of %rdi are clear.

@Joshua And? I don't want them clear. I want them as they were without making the compiler insert a zero/sign-extending mov. That's the whole point.

Instant -2, Do Not Commit in any code review.

@n.m.couldbeanAI  :D Well it can always be prettified, encapsulated and made to use a normal cast on non-x86-64. But it's nice for me to know there's an easy way to do this very specific microthing :).

When u.xx is wider than u.x, it is not certain which 32-bits of 64-bit u.xx are set, the upper or lower half.  That makes code less portable and more maintenance.

I think n.m. hit on the real reason [not to do this]. It would take a paragraph of comments/documentation to explain (with all the rationale against counterarguments presented here). And, what about those g versions that mask off/ignore the upper 32 bits? Suppose, a year or so from now, another programmer is working on g and realizes that they can remove the masking in g because they expect a clean, well formed unsigned long. They never see your optimized f function that gives them a "dirty" unsigned long. A latent bug? Or, lots of comments required in all places?

@CraigEstey Here's a fuller context: I have a function like long applyCallbackInContext(long,long,long,long,long, long (*callback)(long,long,long,long,long)) tailcalled from many functions which have already the first 5 args in place but many times some or all of them are  not full longs but rather ints. Were it not for the zero extending movs, all these could by just a load of a function pointer followed by a jmp on x86-64 (main target). The callbacks will cast back to original types, so any sign/zero extension is just a waste and it adds up due to having many of such wrappers.

@CraigEstey Leaving stuff indeterminate when you're not gonna use it isn't that uncommon or difficult to grasp in C. The above just allows you to do it for register parts too. Use it or not. The above is how it can be done.

inline long long upcast(int v) { long long l; __asm__("" : "=r"(l) : "0" (v));  return l; } avoids a macro.

@RaymondChen Very nice improvement. I like how it does away w/ the union. Don't know why I thought I needed that. Thanks!
